# Javascript not working after publish to IIS

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have searched on the internet for a while now to try and find something similar to help me without succes.

The code I have written below works perfectly on my local host but not on the server, can anyone please offer some advice, happy to add any extra code if required.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#SelectedStillage").on("change", function() {
        var orderid = '@ViewBag.SalesOrder';
        var stillageid = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/DespatchPrintLabels/_itemsPackedInStillage",
            data: {
                orderID: orderid,
                stillageID: $(this).val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#target").html(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Something went wrong ");
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke made your suggested change and it seems to be working now, thanks for your help :)

Comment: You should accept the answer.

Comment: At the time of posting it was Stephen who answered the question in the comments which I upvoted so he would get the credit!

Comment: Stephen already have lots of credit :P just kidding...
I was posting the answer but when I seen it into comment I mention in my answer that I am just making it highlight so it will be useful to others. And btw Stephen himself edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
url: '@Url.Action("_itemsPackedInStillage" "DespatchPrintLabels")'
```